# CSV on RequestBody using Spring

Tags: java, spring, csv, spring-boot, spring-web

I need to receive a csv file on the request and process it.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/csv", consumes = "text/csv")
  public ViewObject postCsv(@RequestBody InputStream request){
// do stuff
}
```

But when I execute:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: text/csv' -d @input.csv http://localhost:8080/csv
```

This is what shows up on my console:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'text/csv;charset=UTF-8' not supported]
```

Spring is saying my request is invalid before anything else.

So, the question is: How to properly receive this csv?

Comment: I believe it should be `@PostMapping(... consumes="text/csv")` _without the trailing semicolon_.  But it's been years since I worked with Spring so I'm not sure enough to post an answer.

Comment: darn! that was a typo on the question! sorry about that

Comment: `@RequestBody` requires an `HttpMessageConverter` for converting the content in the incoming request body to the target data type. Spring Boot does not have an in-built `HttpMessageConverter` for CSV content, therefore does not know how to convert the incoming request body, and hence the exception. A custom `HttpMessageConverter` will have to be written and configured to support CSV content. See [this](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/csv-msg-converter.html) as an example.

Comment: For a list of media types supported out-of-the-box, see `org.springframework.http.MediaType`.

Comment: @kiosia For future reference ALWAYS copy/paste code, NEVER retype into your question.

Answer (score 1):

As someone mentioned in comments, one approach is to implement your own HttpMessageConverter - there are examples of varying quality available on the web.

Another option if you already have some code for parsing CSVs using Spring's `org.springframework.core.io.Resource` classes is to change your method signature as follows to use Spring's built in `ResourceHttpMessageConverter`:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/csv", consumes = "application/octet-stream")
    public ViewObject postCsv(@RequestBody Resource resource){
    // do stuff
}
```